Can a panel dataset consist of units sampled at random points in time?
I have a data frame with the variables $Judge\ ID$ (uniquely identifies judges), $Case\ ID$ (uniquely identifies court cases), $Decision$ (records case outcome), and $Comp\ Date$ (datetime variable specifying when case was completed). Each observation in the dataset corresponds to a unique case. Some judges oversee more cases than others, and—in general—cases are not completed at the same time and date. Is this an unbalanced panel dataset? I know that unbalanced panel data is defined as when at least one panel unit (e.g. a judge) is not observed every period. However, in this dataset, there are an indefinite number of periods since $Comp\ Date$ records datetime which is a continuous variable. If this data frame is not unbalanced panel data, what type of statistical data is it?
